# data transformation-calculate total cost based on aws services and percentage in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:
df1:

```
Product    line_item_product_code       Account    percentage
COMMON      AWSCloudTrail                AU-LOG     20  
COMMON      AWSGlue                      AU-LOG     30
COMMON      AWSQueueService              AU-LOG     50
COMMON      AWSSecretsManager            AU-PRD     40
COMMON      AmazonDynamoDB               AU-PRD     60
```

Second dataframe: df2

```
Account             Product               cost
AU-LOG       COMMON-PROD1                  10
AU-LOG       COMMON-PROD2                  12
AU-PRD       COMMON-PROD1                  14
AU-PRD       COMMON-PROD2                  16
```

Here total cost in df1 for a given account will match the total cost for that account in df2. The dataframe I want is:

So the calculation is to split total cost for a given account and product in df2 across various aws services
based on percentage column in df1 and no of aws services are being used by a particular product.

Ex:In **AU-LOG** account there 3 different `line_item_product_code` and percentage is `20,30,50` .In **df2** for **AU-LOG** account
**COMMON-PROD1**  cost is $10 So this $10 will be splitted across 3 different line_item_product_code using the
percentage mentioned in **df1**

```
Product          line_item_product_code  cost      Account    percentage 
COMMON-PROD1     AWSCloudTrail           2         AU-LOG       20  
COMMON-PROD1     AWSGlue                 3         AU-LOG       30
COMMON-PROD1     AWSQueueService         5         AU-LOG       50
COMMON-PROD2     AWSCloudTrail           2.4       AU-LOG       20  
COMMON-PROD2     AWSGlue                 3.6       AU-LOG       30
COMMON-PROD2     AWSQueueService         6         AU-LOG       50
COMMON-PROD1     AWSSecretsManager       5.6       AU-PRD       40
COMMON-PROD1     AmazonDynamoDB          8.4       AU-PRD       60
COMMON-PROD2     AWSSecretsManager       6.4       AU-PRD       40
COMMON-PROD2     AmazonDynamoDB          9.6       AU-PRD       60
```

How can I achieve this using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple merge should do, the multiply the cost column (which at this point contains the total product cost from df2) by the percentage / 100:

```
>>> df = pd.merge(df1.drop(columns=['Product']), df2, on='Account', how='left')
>>> df['cost'] = df['cost'] * df['percentage'] / 100
>>> df
  line_item_product_code Account  percentage       Product  cost
0          AWSCloudTrail  AU-LOG          20  COMMON-PROD1   2.0
1          AWSCloudTrail  AU-LOG          20  COMMON-PROD2   2.4
2                AWSGlue  AU-LOG          30  COMMON-PROD1   3.0
3                AWSGlue  AU-LOG          30  COMMON-PROD2   3.6
4        AWSQueueService  AU-LOG          50  COMMON-PROD1   5.0
5        AWSQueueService  AU-LOG          50  COMMON-PROD2   6.0
6      AWSSecretsManager  AU-PRD          40  COMMON-PROD1   5.6
7      AWSSecretsManager  AU-PRD          40  COMMON-PROD2   6.4
8         AmazonDynamoDB  AU-PRD          60  COMMON-PROD1   8.4
9         AmazonDynamoDB  AU-PRD          60  COMMON-PROD2   9.6
```